# Does SQL Server perform instance recovery after clean shutdown compared to Oracle Database?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, recovery, instance, shutdown

If Oracle detects that an instance recovery is needed (like issuing shutdown abort command or crash happens), it will initialize recovery process. What about SQL Server? Does it behave in the same way?

In other words, if I perform clean shutdown of SQL Server instance (like Stop sql server using Services console or issue shutdown command in SSMS) and then startup instance, then will recovery process be performed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the recovery process is done on each database everytime the instance start. (and in other scenario as well, like an AG failover for example)

If it was stopped in a clean way, there will be no open transaction to roll foward or roll back so the recovery will be done faster.